# How to Donut caching in Asp.net Core 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to create a quick page load response in **ASP.NET MVC** .

If I use **[outputCache]** then it saves the whole page with the dynamic parts and then a new client will see previous client information.

*What is the Best Practice to Do It?*

I saw that there is a Cache Tag Helper but will it be faster?
Because I still have to go into the Action and and rendering the page except for the section of the Cache Tag Helper.

Many thanks to those who have an optimal and fast solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the docs for [response caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-5.0#responsecache-attribute), Microsoft has a prominent warning:

> Disable caching for content that contains information for
> authenticated clients. Caching should only be enabled for content that
> doesn't change based on a user's identity or whether a user is signed
> in.

As you indicate, your scenario involves dynamic authenticated content. Thus you should avoid caching the rendered output as a whole, and maybe consider caching specific data or elements within a page *only* if you're very careful and performance requires it. Otherwise, safer to leave defaults. ASP.NET Core is very fast -- it's unlikely the rendering is the bottleneck in most cases.

Comment: thank you very much for the help. As I thought this is the situation at the moment.